# SEO for different content displayed via PHP

Tags: seo, php

Do search engines index, crawl, and display content that is shown only to certain users via php?

For example, I have a page which looks like this:

some content1

*php if user is x user*

some content2 for user x

*php if user is y user*

different content3.

So, would the search engines consider the keywords/links/seo of all three types of content or just that displayed to all users?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They would see the stuff served to all users. They don't login or have accounts so any customized information will not be shown to them and thus they'll never see it or index it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the might read the code on the page and thereby index the content. I appreciate the clarification